# How long is the typical peptide sequence recognized by a T-cell?

Tags: immunology, protein-binding

A naive T-cell recognizes either a certain sequence of amino-acids (even if that sequence occurs as a part of a longer sequence of amino-acids(*)), or a small set(**) thereof.  Only T-cells that do not recognize any sequences native to their own organism are allowed to mature.  Then they are released from the thymus and start searching for the amino-acid sequences they recognize, assuming that their occurrence within the body would indicate proteins synthesized, and possibly forming, another organism (a parasite).  **I wonder what are the shortest, longest, and typical lengths of the sequences recognized by a matured T-cell, as counted in amino-acids.**

(I suppose that if a naive T-cell recognized any very short peptide, it would be unlikely to survive in the thymus, and if it only recognized very long peptides, it would be overspecialized and evolutionarily unstable.  So there must be some limits.)

If the answer varies across vertebrate species significantly, that would be interesting, too.

Footnotes:

*: *In this sense I used the term "peptide" loosely in the title formulation of my question.  Please correct me if such usage was simply wrong.*

**:*I don't have a good understanding of how the "sets" are represented in the T-cell, and consequently, how they can be structured - whether they tend to form a single "pattern with wildcards" or multiple independent patterns, or anything in between.*